# Reliably detect Python 3 development files

Tags: python, header-file

I have a shell script which installs all required packages for a project. Some of those packages are Python 3 based and require to compile things and for this the Python sources need to be installed<sup>1</sup> (e.g. the `python3-dev` package in common Debian-based distributions). Otherwise, unintelligible/misleading compile error messages will be displayed (missing header files) which is something I want to prevent.

Now I thought it might be best to try to detect whether the Python 3 sources are already installed and in case they aren't not even attempt to run `pip` but instead instruct the user to get the Python sources for his/her distribution and maybe also some instructions for the most common ones.

In short: How can I reliably detect whether the Python 3 header files are installed on various distributions (and maybe even in non-Linux environments going as far as Cygwin)?

---

<sub>1. The package is `mypy` and parts of the error messages include:</sub>

> ```
> ast27/Parser/acceler.c:13:25: fatal error: pgenheaders.h: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> ```
>
> […]
>
> ```
>  Command "/path/to/my/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-x0e2zn8t/typed-ast/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uythmwn1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /path/to/my/venv/include/site/python3.5/typed-ast" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-x0e2zn8t/typed-ast/
> ```

Comment: Would a kind of `find / -type f -name 'whatever is needed'` or a kind of condition check like `[[ -f file_required ]]` provide a good info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, basically I just need to check for the existence of `python3-config` in the `PATH` (`command -v python3-config >/dev/null`), this signifies that here are Python 3 development files.

If I would want to go even further I could theoretically also use this tool to get the include directories which I could check for some of the particular header files required but I see no need for this.

BTW, applies to Python 2 and Python 2.7+ similarly (`python2-config` and `python2.7-config` respectively).